# Load local javascript in webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift, webview

I'm making mobile browser with my own ads in Swift and I want to run script. I already inject JavaScript local file but it opens in other window and overrides webView content. Is it possible to run JavaScript code in webView page? Not in other window, only in page with page content.

Comment: Are you using a `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`? I recommend using `WKWebView` for using javascript methods AFTER the view has loaded.

Comment: I'm using UIWebView,thanks for advice

Comment: you want to inject a .js file or you want to execute some javascript code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Using `WKWebView` for javascript method call:

**Step 1.** Import class for webkit

Obj-C: `#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>`
Swift:  `import WebKit`

**Step 2.** Create a `WKWebView` instance (Unfortunately it can only be done programatically)

Obj-C `@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView *wkWebView;`

Swift `var wkWebView: WKWebView? = WKWebView()`

**Step 3.** Then in `viewDidLoad`

Obj-C:

```
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    
    NSString *scriptSourceCode = @"your javascript code here";
    WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:source injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:YES];

    WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [controller addUserScript:script];

    configuration.userContentController = controller;
    
    _wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configuration];
    
    [self.view addSubview:_wkWebView];
```

Swift:

```
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let controller = WKUserContentController()
    
    let scriptSourceCode = "your javascript code here"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSourceCode, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    controller.addUserScript(script)

    configuration.userContentController = controller
    
    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
    
    self.view.addSubview(self.wkWebView!)
```

**Step 4** Load a HTML string (or a loadRequest) in the `wkWebView`:

Obj-C:

```
[_wkWebView loadHTMLString:_desiredHTML baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

Swift:

```
self.wkWebView?.loadHTMLString(_desiredHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

**Step 5**. Call a method which exists in the javascript included in the `WKWebView`

Obj-C:

```
    NSString *callMethod = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"existingMethodWithParam(%@)", stringParam];

    [_wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:callMethod
             completionHandler:^(id obj, NSError *error) {
                 
                 if (error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"ERROR evaluating JavaScript - %@", error);
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Returned value - %@", obj); //if the javascript method has a return type
                 }
             }];
```

Swift:

```
let callMethod = "existingMethodWithParam()"
self.wkWebView?.evaluateJavaScript(callMethod) { obj, error in
    print(obj)
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: and where i must insert script? in here: "existingMethodWithParam(%@)" ?

Comment: @CDDsw: For example, on some button action when u want to call the js method. OR Do u want to call that method when the webview loads?

Comment: I want to load js with webview content not in other window when viewDidLoad.I already have this function,but i want to know how to run js with webview content.I'm making browser where ads come out when page did load,like adsense ads,or want to know is it possible?

Comment: I have edited **Step 3**. It now accepts a js script code which will be executed at DocumentStart. Hope this helps