# Is it possible that display adsense in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, adsense

I tried to display adsense in UIWebView. like...

```
NSString *test = @"
    <script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'>
    </script>
    <ins class='adsbygoogle'
        style='display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px'
        data-ad-client='ca-pub--------------'
        data-ad-slot='-------'>
    </ins>
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
"
[webView loadHTMLString:test baseURL:nil];
```

There is just empty space.
How can I display it?

Comment: Please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582198/load-local-javascript-in-webview
It will help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You Can't The use of AdSense for mobile in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3394713?hl=en&ref_topic=1250104#2