# How to evaluateJavaScript when app goes to background WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, background, wkwebview, evaluatejavascript, wkuserscript

I am create html page with HTML5 IMA SDK player and then load this page to WKWebView, all work fine pause, playing content etc, but I want "pause" content when app goes to background for achieve this I did tried used  "WKWebView evaluateJavaScript" but this code don't work when app goes to background and did tried this answer ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482566/wkwebview-doesnt-run-javascript-when-on-background#:~:text=Javascript%20is%20disabled%20by%20default,WKWebView%20should%20look%20like%20this.&text=Also%20you%20can%20check%20this%20post%20to%20see%20a%20different%20approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482566/wkwebview-doesnt-run-javascript-when-on-background#:%7E:text=Javascript%20is%20disabled%20by%20default,WKWebView%20should%20look%20like%20this.&text=Also%20you%20can%20check%20this%20post%20to%20see%20a%20different%20approach)) but this don't help me, keyWindow is deprecated and I use another approach:

```
let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .map({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
            .compactMap({$0})
            .first?.windows
            .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
```

Also doesn't work.

Which way exist for "evaluateScript" when app goes to background or before app will go to background?